# File descriptors: troubles in storing a read int value into a variable

Tags: c, file, int, descriptor

I'm trying to work with file descriptos. I've been teached to use filestreams (fopen, fread etc.), but now I want to understand this other way to use files.

This code I'm gonna post is kinda trivial and stupid: it simply opens a file called "file", which has the following structure: 4 characters, an integer and a '\n' value per line. I'm not trying to do anything useful, I'm just trying to do some basic operations I used to do with incredible ease using the streams. In particular, my file has this information:

```
row 1
row 2
row 3
```

"row" and the space represents the 4 characters, the number represents the integer. I'd just like to print the file content, but I want to memorize the int value I encounter (otherwise printing every character met would have been enough) in a variable (so I could do some elaborations based on that value, if I want to). This is the code I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);

    char *buffer;

    buffer = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    unsigned char x;
    int y = -1;
    int number = 1;
    int i=0, j;

    while(read(fd, &x, 1*sizeof(char)) > 0) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            buffer[i] = x;
            i++;
            read(fd, &x, sizeof(char)); // or 1 instead of sizeof(char)
        }
        buffer[i] = x;
        buffer[i+1] = '\0';
        printf("byte read: %d\n", read(fd, &y, sizeof(int))); // or 4 instead of sizeof(int): it's the same
        printf("number read: %d\n", y); // crap value
        printf("%s%d\n", buffer, y);

        read(fd, &x, 1); // discard the new line
        i=0;
    }
close(fd);
}
```

Here's the trouble: when I try to store the int value, since sizeof(int) means 4 bytes, it just reads 4 characters. So the file descriptor advance of 4 characters and the program simply doesn't do what I'd like to do (it "eats" the following characters: '\n', 'r', 'o'). I can't understand how to tell that the following character is a integer, and should take up 4 bytes of memory. So if a try to write 4 digit numbers in the file, the format display is correct but it memorize a wrong value (since it sees 4 characters, not a number ... ), that has nothing to do with the integer in the file.

If I can't do this way, I was thinking about memorizing the number in a string, and then convert the string to a number.. but I saw some codes which did exacly as I did in my code, so I'm getting quite confused.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: If this is a text file why would you expect reading the 4 character bytes in the string to equal the value of the integer variable that you store it in. If it is a text based file, read the text in as a string then use a conversion function to convert it to the integer value represented by the string

Comment: In practice, you should `read` a large buffer (kilobytes), and you should always keep the number of read bytes (i.e. the count returned by `read`)

Answer (score 5):

You seem to confuse integers printed out as characters/bytes in a file, and `int` variables ('that take up 4 bytes of memory' as you say) inside your program.

The `read()` function simply reads bytes (or `char`s) from your file. This function has no idea what kind of stuff you're reading.

If you want to get an `int`, you need to convert the bytes you read into an `int`. Have a look at [`sscanf()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sscanf/), [`strtol()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/), ...

BTW, `int`s indeed often take up 4 bytes of space, but that not always the case; it depends on the platform.